# Enumerate in tabular creates unwanted vertical space

Tags: tables, enumerate, enumitem

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm}}
    Head & Content\\
    \hline
    Foo &
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{\arabic*.}}, itemindent=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep]
        \item A
        \item B
    \end{enumerate}
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which produces unwanted vertical space before and after the list:

[image]

However adding surrounding text renders as expected:

```
\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm}}
    Head & Content\\
    \hline
    Foo &
    How does
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{\arabic*.}}, itemindent=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep]
        \item A
        \item B
    \end{enumerate}
    this work?
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Comment: Technically, lists use \ifvmode to detect when they are inside a paragraph or between paragraphs (and add extra space).

Answer (score 10):

Maybe it's simpler to define a variant of `enumerate` for use in tables, with specific parameters. I borrowed the `\compress` command from an answer on this site: it makes latex believe the list  is at the very beginning of a minipage, so latex adds  no vertical spacing before lists.

I also used the rules from `booktabs`, which have some vertical padding, and a variable thickness.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{tabenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[tabenum]{label=\arabic*. ,wide=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep, itemsep=2pt, font = \bfseries, after=\vspace{-\baselineskip}, before=\compress}
\usepackage{array, booktabs}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\compress}{\@minipagetrue}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm}}
    Head & Content\\
    \midrule
    Foo &
    \begin{tabenum}
        \item A. Some text some text some text
        \item B
    \end{tabenum}
    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You can add the `\compress` with `before=\compress` to the list settings.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, Ulrike! I've incorporated to the code. Thanks:-)

Comment: Thanks for the idea! While this does solve the problem with vertical space before the enum, space afterwards is not dynamically calculated. Appended text will be placed ‘inside’ the enumeration.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `before` and `after` options in order to adjust the space before and after the list to your needs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{l p{4cm}}
    Head & Content\\
    \hline
    Foo &
    \begin{enumerate}[label={\textbf{\arabic*.}}, itemindent=0pt, leftmargin=*, nosep,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-0.5\baselineskip}]
        \item A
        \item B
    \end{enumerate}
    \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That sure is a solution, but also hard coded. Is there a flexible solution? I thought `enumitem` could handle this situation.